# Verification of a pre-stored image using camera

Tags: android, ocr

Trying to learn about how to verify an image which is stored inside android app ( somewhere in Asset folder ) to a card which already has some logo (check if both the logo are identical) using camera .
Was reading about Open CV but it is all in C++ . Need Java code.

Any rough idea or document or link or tutorial anything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of JavaCV, it's a port of OpenCV.

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv